# silverlight project setup

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight

i have a a new silverlight solution in visual studio.  i have created a silverlight class library to share common functionality.  this class library has a service reference and so it has a ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file.  the problem is if i create a project in this solution and add a reference to the class library it seems that i need a ServiceReferences.ClientConfig in this individual project. if i copy and paste the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file from the class library to the project, everything works fine.  if i do not i get the error below.  doesnt this defeat the purpose of sharing this service reference in a class library? i want to be able to change where the service reference points to (debug machine / production machine) easily in one place.  what can i do? is there another way i'm missing? Thank you.

> Cannot find 'ServiceReferences.ClientConfig' in the .xap application package. This file is used to configure client proxies for web services, and allows the application to locate the services it needs. Either include this file in the application package, or modify your code to use a client proxy constructor that specifies the service address and binding explicitly. Please see inner exception for details. >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config for the class library is not packaged into the .xap file. Without that configuration, the service reference cannot be properly configured.

> doesnt this defeat the purpose of sharing this service reference in a class library?

Not really. The bulk of the "service reference" is the code in the class library. This is what you are sharing. Since a xap (or exe and web app) has only one config file, you must have the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig in the *application's* config file.

I am not aware of a mechanism to copy some important bits from the config file of a class library to the application config file during a build.